# Is it possible to inject ngAria into an Angular 2 project?

Tags: angular, typescript, wai-aria

I have looked around for articles, github repo's and many more sources of information to answer this question. All I can see is ngAria being used in Angular 1.0 (regular JS). However I am using Angular 2.0 and need to know if this is possible in Typescript (Any conversion methods).

Here is a link where I have found one use of ngAria being implemented into Angular 2.

https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/handout/a11y/

Any response/help is much appreciated.

Thank you!